# Add a 'cloud' band to Sentinel 2 images (GEE)

Tags: sentinel-2, google-earth-engine, cloud-cover

This script is used to mask out cloud in sentinel 2 images using a threshold for band 4:

```js
// Sentinel 2 cloud function 
var cloudfunction_ST2 = function(image) {
  // If band 4 is higher than 2500, the pixel is considered as cloudy.
  var b4 = image.select("B4");
  // Get pixels above the threshold.
  var cloud = b4.gt(2500);      
  // Create a mask from high likelihood pixels.
  var cloudmask = image.mask().and(cloud.not());
  // Mask those pixels from the image.
  return image.updateMask(cloudmask);
};
```

My question is, how to add a 'cloud' band to the image collection?

Comment: I suggest you include some examples of where there are issues with your cloudmasking results. For example, include the following snippet, after changing the dates and location to highlight a problem area.

var sample_image = ee.Image(
  ee.ImageCollection ('COPERNICUS/S2')
    .filterDate('2017-01-01', '2017-01-11')
    .filterBounds(ee.Geometry.Point(-90.79, 15.54))
    .map(cloudfunction_ST2)
    .first()
  );
Map.centerObject(sample_image);
Map.addLayer(
  sample_image,
  {bands:'B4,B3,B2', min:0, max:3000, gamma:1.5},
  'sample'
);

Answer (score 1):

If you want the value of 'cloud' to be 1 (true) do:

```js
// Sentinel 2 cloud function 
var cloudfunction_ST2 = function(image) {
  // If band 4 is higher than 2500, the pixel is considered as cloudy.
  var b4 = image.select("B4");
  // Get pixels above the threshold.
  var cloud = b4.gt(2500).select([0], ["cloud"]);
  // Create a mask from high likelihood pixels.
  var cloudmask = image.mask().and(cloud.not())
  image = image.updateMask(cloudmask);
  // Mask those pixels from the image.
  return image.addBands(cloud)
};
```

Otherwise:

```js
// Sentinel 2 cloud function 
var cloudfunction_ST2 = function(image) {
  // If band 4 is higher than 2500, the pixel is considered as cloudy.
  var b4 = image.select("B4");
  // Get pixels above the threshold.
  var cloud = b4.gt(2500);
  // Create a mask from high likelihood pixels.
  var cloudmask = image.mask().and(cloud.not()).select([0], ["cloud"])
  image = image.updateMask(cloudmask);
  // Mask those pixels from the image.
  return image.addBands(cloudmask)
};
```

Then, when you go `ImageCollection.map(cloudfunction_ST2)` you'll get an extra band called 'cloud' in every image.

Remember you have a band called 'QA60' which is the *bit mask band with cloud mask information*.