# Cloud masking Rapid Eye images

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, cloud-cover

I am trying to delete clouds (ideally also their shadows) from Rapid Eye images (5 bands; blue, green, red, red edge, near-infrared).

I have tried to set a threshold for the red band and mask accordingly, inspired by [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/254718/add-a-cloud-band-to-sentinel-2-images-gee) question but it doesn't pick up the clouds, but only other areas (such as parts of a lake and vegetation and also a few of the clouds shadows). I have also tried to modify the algorithm: ee.Algorithms.Landsat.simpleCloudScore() without success (don't know if it would even be possible to modify landsat algorithms and apply to other images).

Is there any other convenient way to mask the clouds?

Comment: Do you have a script to share? Can't you use the Unusable Data Mask (UDM), which I believe the imagery should come with? You should be fine adjusting a Landsat cloud scoring algorithm. Just make sure the band names and range of values (e.g. 0-1 or 0-10000) match what the algorithm expects.

Comment: Thanks. Solved it by simply adjusting the threshold far more than I initially thought I would have to... Is it possible to use Landsat algorithms on other images than actual Landsat?